# How do I add keys dynamically to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
 for x in names:
        dictionary = {x : [], }
```

I want my dictionary to have an empty list of every element of names, yet I'm only getting the last one (overriding, obviously). In lists we can use  `.append()`. How do I do this with a dictionary?

**Edit** : Assuming names has Jimmy and Alex.

```
dictionary = {Jimmy : [], Alex : []}
```

Comment: You're creating new dicts at each iteration. OTOH, better to use `collections.defaultdict` than preallocating lists at each key.

Comment: Right,noticed, any clue on how to get the end result i described.

Comment: Can you please provide an example output of your desired dictionary, what exactly do you mean with "list of every element of names"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create a new dict each time, instead add the name to the same one.

```
dictionary = {}
for x in names:
    dictionary[x] = []
```

or, for short:

```
dictionary = {x: [] for x in names}
```